# More from links in Instant Articles

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

We have a few feeds for Facebook Instant articles that are setup across multiple pages:

- https://www.facebook.com/TheUrbanListPER
- https://www.facebook.com/TheUrbanListSYD

Our Instant Articles are showing fine however there is one problem…

In the "More From" section posts from TheUrbanListPER are appearing in TheUrbanListSYD and visa versa.

Both TheUrbanListPER and TheUrbanListSYD are seperate pages with seperate feeds. So the only thing I can think of is that Facebook is using the root domain for matching?

How can I restrict the "More From…" to the current page?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/guides/publishertools#connect:

> **Types of URLs**
>   You have 3 choices to determine which stories will be made available for publication as Instant Articles: via a root domain, via a subdomain or via a specific path within a domain. This page summarizes the factors to consider before choosing which version of your URL is best to register with Instant Articles.

So set up your feeds accordingly, for example by making them available under different paths.